# (Updated) Geometric Illustration of Monotone and Maximal Monotone Maps

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am writing a note about the Monotone and Maximal Monotone maps from the following book

http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2Fb97594

In this book we read a map $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightrightarrows\mathbb{R}^n$ is called monotone, if it's graph is monotone, namely,
$$\langle u-v,x-y\rangle\ge0,\forall u\in T(x),\forall v\in T(y)$$
and is maximal if its graph is not properly contained in the graph of any other monotone operator
$$\langle u-v,x-y\rangle\ge0,\forall v\in T(y),y\in \text{dom}\;T\Rightarrow u\in T(x).$$

> So at least for $n=1,2,3$, I want to have a geometric illustration, for example the function $f(x)=x,\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is monotone, since for every $x_1<x_2$ we have $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$, But now here our maps are set valued so I want to know for example for $n=1$ this definition of monotone maps means that for $x_1<x_2$, $\sup T(x_1)<\sup T(x_2)$($\sup T(x_1)>\sup T(x_2)$), if so then how? But for $n=2,3,...$ $x_1<x_2$ is not meaningful?! and similarly for Maximal Monotone I don't know even for functions such $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ what does this definition mean?

I searched to find some nice geometric graph of such maps and could not find anything!
Also I need some nice or new examples of such maps, So if you have some examples of these type of maps in your researches, any lecture or book, it would be appropriate to refer me to them.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is a "geometric illustration" as well as an "excellent example" for you? You want only maximal monotone operators in finite dimensions? The literature on maximal monotone operators is extremely broad.

Comment: @NeutralElement Well, I've edited my question!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=1$ the structure of the graph of a maximal monotone operator is known.

First the domain and range of such an operator are (possibly degenerate) intervals. If the domain is just one value then the graph is a vertical line passing through that value (similarly for the range being degenerate).

If the domain is a non-degenerate interval ($(a,b)$ or $(a,b]$ or $[a,b)$ or $[a,b]$ or $(a,+\infty)$ or $[a,+\infty)$ or $(-\infty,b)$ or $(-\infty,b]$ or $\mathbb{R}$) an operator $T:D(T)\subset\mathbb{R}\rightrightarrows\mathbb{R}$ is maximal monotone iff $T$  is monotone; $T$ has closed convex (interval) values; the graph is increasing in the sense that, for every $t\in[a,b)\cap\mathbb{R}$, $\inf T((t,+\infty))=\sup T(t)$ and, for every $t\in(a,b]\cap\mathbb{R}$,  $\sup T((-\infty,t))=\inf T(t)$; and a condition at the boundary: $T(a)=T(a)+\mathbb{R}_{-}$ whenever $a\in D(T)$ and $T(b)=T(b)+\mathbb{R}_{+}$ whenever $b\in D(T)$. Here $(a,b)$  is the interior of $D(T)$ the domain of $T$.

For a general $n\ge2$, the following recent result of Lohne holds: an operator $T:D(T)\subset\mathbb{R^n}\rightrightarrows\mathbb{R^n}$ is maximal monotone iff $T$  is monotone; $T$ has convex values; $D(T)$ is nearly-convex in the sense that there is a convex set $C$ such that $C\subset D(T)\subset\overline{C}$; $T=T+N_{D(T)}$; and $T$ has a closed graph.

Here $N_{D(T)}$ denotes the normal cone to $D(T)$.

Some references from where I took these results:

MR2465513 (2010c:47121) Löhne, Andreas, A characterization of maximal monotone operators. Set-Valued Anal.  16  (2008),  no. 5-6, 693–700.

MR2899842 Voisei, M. D., Characterizations and continuity properties for maximal monotone operators with non-empty domain interior. J. Math. Anal. Appl.  391  (2012),  no. 1, 119–138.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the source of maximal monotone mappings in the following and the references therein:

1. Variational Analysis, Rockafellar, R. Tyrrell, Wets, Roger J.-B.
   http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540627722
2. Maximal Monotone Operators in Banach Spaces, Viorel Barbu
   http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-5542-5_2
3. Lectures on Maximal Monotone Operators, R. R. Phelps
   http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9302209.pdf
4. Convex Functions, Monotone Operators and Differentiability, R. R. Phelps
   http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-540-46077-0